# How to show the lifting property of an operator described in its ellipticity

Tags: operator-theory, besov-space

Consider Soblev spaces as special cases of Besov spaces characterized by wavelets, $H^s = B^s_{2,2}$.

I want to prove the following statement.
For a positive definite self-adjoint operator $A$, if the following satisfies for any $f\in H^s$ with $s>0$,

$$\langle Af, f\rangle \simeq \|f\|_{H^{-t/2}},$$

where $\simeq$ means equality holds up to an independent constant of $f$ and $t>0$, then $A$ has the lifting property such that $A:H^s \to H^{s+t}$.

It seems to be a rather standard property used in literature, e.g. [this](http://epubs.siam.org/doi/abs/10.1137/S0036142902411793) and [this](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/cpa.20042/abstract).

Comment: characterizing the operators $H^s \to H^{s+t}$ is easier in the Fourier domain ?

Comment: @user1952009 But my final goal is to study the space with bounded domain (periodic functions).

Comment: so ? $f \in H^s([0;1]) \Leftrightarrow  \| \ |1+n|^s \hat{f}(n)  \|_{l^2(\mathbb{Z})} < \infty$ (or $\|.\|_{l^2(\mathbb{Z^d})}$ in the $d$ dimensional case)